# Windows 7 using symlinks in cmd

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd, symlink

I am trying to use symlinks with ffmpeg through a commandline but cmd seems to be treating the symlink files as if they were actual files and not pointing ffmpeg to the correct files.

I need to convert an image sequence to a video file which is easy enough. The problem is ffmpeg can only take in an image sequence starting from frame 1. My images are nameg e.g my_img_009.jpg, my_img_010.jpg etc.

So I made symlinks. One called my_img_001.jpg that is linked to my_img_009.jpg, another called my_img_002.jpg that is linked to my_img_010.jpg etc etc.

when I run it ffmpeg just tells me the file C:\my_img_%3d.jpg isn't a valid image file. So it is trying to process the file instead of following it to the real file.

My commandline is:
    C:\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\my_img_%3d.jpg C:\output.mov

Note: %3d tells ffmpeg that this is a sequence. The % means number and '3d' means a padding of three zeros. i.e '001' instead of '01' which would be %2d

Please help

Comment: What method did you use to create symlinks?

Comment: used cmd wih the following command: mklink C:\mylink_001.jpg \\server\myimg_005.jpg

Comment: Did you try to copy the files to the local drive and create the links as a hardlinks (mklink with /h option)?

Comment: No i didnt, I can't copy them locally because the point of this script is to process images off a server and that kind of defeats the point. Do you think a hardlink to a file on the server would work?

Comment: Hardlinks can only be created on local volumes. That's why I was writing about copying files. You can also try to create a hardlink on server and access the hardlink through network.
Hardlinks may help because they are impossible to distinguish from the original file.

Answer (score -2):

enable them first 
fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation
fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation [L2L:{0|1}] | [L2R:{0|1}] | [R2R:{0|1}] | [R2L:{0|1}]